# Selenium(Java) - Creating Log Files while running Selenium script from a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver

I need to run my Selenium(Java) script in different machine. So I'm exporting the script to a jar and executing it from a batch file. I would like to know if there is anyway I can create a log for my script while executing it from a batch file and store it somewhere.

While running the script in my local(using Eclipse) I'm able to do that with the help of `log4j` but I'm not sure how to do the same while executing the script in a different machine. (Note: It would be great if there is any way I can do this, by using `log4j` itself.)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourcommand &>filename
```

where `yourcommand` is executing the batch file from command line, something like

`file.bat &>logfile.log`

(redirects both stdout and stderr to filename).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? Where and when it should be used and What does `yourcommand` in your answer mean?

Comment: Thanks for adding info. But I still have some questions.
I'm using `java -jar testfile.jar` to execute my Selenium script from a batch file and I'm not sure how adding `&>logfile.log` to it will create a log file. Where and how exactly the log file will be created?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `log4j` that means that you have a properties file. When you create the executable jar it should also include that file.

In the properties file, for your logs you should have a line like this:

```
log4j.appender.dest1.File=C:\\Users\\Your_User\\workspace\\Manual.logs
```

Edit the line to be like:

```
log4j.appender.dest1.File=Manual.logs
```

Add the "Manual.logs" (or the name that you defined) file next to the jar executable. This way, as long as both files are in the same folder, your logs are going to be generated.